# Are there limits to editing questions by third parties?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

My example is this [drastic edit to the question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68790/conceptual-doubts-in-em-waves-and-old-quantum-theory) I had replied to, which is a drastic rewrite.

Are the original questioners asked to approve of the change even though their reputation is below 10?

Comment: That edit doesn't look that drastic to me, it seems to change mostly formatting, grammar and spelling. It looks drastic on first glance because the diff engine doesn't break out the differences and just displays whole blocks to be changed.

Comment: How is that drastic? When I had proposed the edit, all I had done was change the formatting and the grammar, removed rude capitalisation like "I DON'T UNDERSTAND THIS!!!!!!!!!!11", and got rid of the exclamation mrks like, "The famous question of how the electron does not foall into the nucleus!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!11111" etc. Then, after that, the edit by the edit reviewer was to just only remove the "Thanks in advance!" and changed the title.

Comment: @dimension10     well, it changed the tone of the questions, turning it from maybe an eager student to possibly a crack pot. In that sense drastic, because one replies differently in the two cases.

Comment: @annav: The first version didn't sound at all, like an eager student. It sounded more like screaming "Give me answers, or else... How dare you people not answer my question?"

Answer (score 2):

Regarding that particular question, it's not been drastically edited. Formatting and grammar has been improved, that's pretty much it. (look closely).

But in general, radical edits get rejected as "too radical". Note that the OP gets a notification of an edit or a suggested edit, so s/he can always rollback or reject it.

Comment: Just to be clear, I know the OP gets notified if a low-rep user *suggests* an edit, and they can participate in approving or rejecting it. But are you saying they also get notified if a high-rep user just *makes* an edit?

Comment: @Chris: yes, if the edit is non-trivial. For details, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134906/what-type-of-notifications-do-we-have?lq=1#comment378020_135411

Comment: @ChrisWhite In fact, I just got [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B0QaP.png) when logging in :)